# LibreOffice Impress: change screen format from 4:3 to 16:9 without stretching images?

Tags: libreoffice

I have a presentation made with libreoffice impress with slide format 4:3. I want to change the format to 16:9. However, when doing this, all images are stretched/scaled horizontally. It is a pain to re-scale them one by one manually.

There is a solution for powerpoint: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToConvertAPowerPointPresentationFrom43RatioTo169WithoutDistortedOrStretchedImages.aspx

Any idea for libreoffice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a little experimentation:

I assume you already know how to change the format of the slide, and when you do this there are two methods I found for maintaining the images on the slide:

- You can select the images(s) in the screen, cut them (ctrl-x) chage the format and then paste the images back in (ctrl-v)
- In the dialog for changing the screen size, there is a checkbox titled "Fit Object to paper format" - clear this checkbox, and the images on the page will not be re-scaled.  You will need to re-position them.

[image]

Comment: This is not a solution if changing an already made presentation, since all the objects will end up running off the bottom of the slides. It appears as though the transfer from 4:3 to 19:9 just changes the height of the slide, and does not scale the content to this new height.

Comment: The _built-in_ 4:3 / 16:10 / 16:9 size all have same width 28cm and different heights 21cm / 17.5cm / 15.75cm.  So going to higher ratio just cuts off 4 or 5cm off the bottom.  However, you can _type whatever you want in Width : Height_ fields_!  If you keep Height 21cm but compute Width 21*16/9 = 37.33, nothing will be cut off!  Everything will remain to the left side of the slide, with white margin on the right, which is not pretty but an OK start for editing...

Comment: (Incidentally, if you're converting from projector to presentation over Zoom, having the right side blank is not that bad as your face is overlayed there, and you can keep that corner in mind as you selectively resize pictures & text...)